# In anyway we know from servlet if the client is still waiting

Tags: java, ajax, performance, jsp, servlets

We have a jsp page which submits a request to servlet. But the servlet has to do search in huge number of files and it takes time. In the meantime if client is closed the servlet still does searching and it is a waste of our resources. Is there anyway from servlet we can know if client is still waiting on response? eg: we should know from servlet if our jsp page is closed so that we can stop searching.

Comment: I thnk its not possible because once the request send to server its not possible meanwhile to check the client is available or not.

Comment: This sounds like a design problem to me. If you have a long-running task spawned by web requests, you may be better off executing it asynchronously (with respect to web requests) then presenting results to the web. It's hard to be sure without knowing more about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Http is a stateless protocol. So technically there is no connection state to check. However, here is how you mimic a connection state.

You need to add processing on both the server and the client (web browser).

On the server you can store a hear-beat value in the session object. Heartbeat meaning a time stamp of the last time the client made a request. You establish a threshold value. Let's say 10 seconds. If the client (web browser) has not sent a heart beat message for over 10 seconds you abandon your process.

On the client (web browser) you can use javascript to send a heart beat message every 10 seconds. Use Ajax to send a message to the server. Again that tells the server the client is still waiting.

Note! You need to make sure a session is established on the server. The server needs to store the heat beat messages in session scope. The client will have more than one request per session.

Finally, JSP is a servlet. JSP is simply another way of writing a servlet. Your container (e.g. Tomcat) compiles the JSP in to a servlet. JSP runs on the server, does not run in the web browser. Yes, you can send Javascript and HTML to the web browser from a servlet (or JSP).

Hope that helps.
Good Luck.

Comment: Your solution looks feasible. I would try and update. Thanks for responding on this.

Comment: Glad to have helped:)  Please consider accepting my answer (I.E. mark my answer as accepted). FYI - It may take a little but I now the pattern I described works. I seen it in production :)

Comment: Sorry to ask you this. I am not that good in javascript/ajax. Is there any example that i can refer to send the heartbeat to my servlet.

Comment: No problem. I just entered the search term "javascript send heartbeat" in google and got a ton of hits. The first one looks good http://ajaxpatterns.org/archive/Heartbeat.php .. But there are many others :)